# Getting popular tags from comma separated values in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have tags table and news table. News table has tag_id table as foreign key and is stored as comma separated value if the news has more than 1 tag. I want is to fetch those tags which have more news.
[image]

For example: In the above news table:
Tag id 1 has total 5 news
Tag id 2 has total 4 news
Tag id 3 has total 3 news, and
Tag id 4 has total 2 news.

So, I want to fetch the popular tags from the highest news count to lowest news count in the following order:

1. Politics
2. Health
3. Crime
4. Corona Virus

How do I do that? Please help me!

Comment: Your db model design is bad. Its easier to implement but harder to work with, like you have noticed. You can either fix it by using N:N relationship or select both tables and work it in memory.

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Is it bad? News can have multiple tags, so I added tag_id as foreign key, if thats the issue. I tried almost everything, but no luck.I have also defined Many to Many relationship on the model, but I am not getting the result. Please help!

Comment: @MohitPaudel Read in docs about many to many with pivot table. That architecture is what you need here.

Comment: I came with a different idea all of a sudden, @Tpojka. I have implemented news views increment  on my project, if a user clicked on a news the views are increased. And, it will only be increased if he/she hasn't opened the same news before. I implemented the same concept on tags. I added a column named views and set it to 0 by default, and when some user clicks on a news, then if the news have some tag then the tag views also increases with news views. So, I am fetching trending tags genuinely right? I fetched trending news in the same way by only fetching news whose views are more for today.

Comment: Two different things. You need many to many relation here since article can have many tags and also same multiple tags can be part of different articles. As simple as that.

Comment: Ohh okay. I got it. So, when I create a new article or update an article, the tags of the new or updating article should be added to an associate table or who has fields of tag_id and news_id? And, I shouldn't save tags as a single comma separated value? The site I am building is a news portal. Hundreds of news will be added everyday for the time being, later it could be even more. Please suggest me the best approach. I am confused.

Comment: As what you said. Read thoroughly documentation about eloquent relation and especially manyToMany section. Google for some more articles about "Laravel eloquent many to many examples", also visit YouTube for same request. Having comma separated values in DB is anti-pattern and couldn't serve as strong as relational tables with well set keys. Later it should be as simple as `$news->tags()->attach([1, 2, 3]);` where 1, 2, and 3 are ids of tags. Find some blog packages on github since there you'll be able to see how tags are associated in action.

Comment: Thank you @Tpojka. I will update model relaionship from belongsTo to hasMany and create an associate model, Have a good day!

Comment: It's not `hasMany`. It's `belongsToMany` relation. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Answer (score -1):

The best way to implement this in laravel is by using Many to Many relationship. Create a **news_tag** pivot table with **news_id** & **tag_id** as columns. Then attach the tags upon creating news. Let me share an example with Articles & Tags.

```
class Article extends Model
{    
    public function tags(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Tag::class);
}
```

}

Then your tag Model:

```
class Tag extends Model{
  public function articles(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class);
  }
}
```

Then your pivot table will look like this:

```
class CreateArticleTagTable extends Migration
{

public function up()
{
    Schema::create('article_tag', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('article_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('tag_id');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('article_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('articles')
            ->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->foreign('tag_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('tags')
            ->onDelete('cascade');    
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
  {
    Schema::dropIfExists('article_tag');
  }
}
```

Then in your controller attach the tags. you will need to get the tag id from the tags table and pass it to the view then on your store function post the id and attach it to news_tag like this.

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'heading' => 'required|string|max:191',
        'tag_id' => 'required|integer',
    ]);

    if($request->isMethod('post')){
        $article = new Article;
        $article->heading = $request['heading'];
        $article->tag_id = $request['tag_id'];
        $article->save();
        //attach tags
        $article->tags()->attach(request('tag_id'));

    }
}
```

Comment: Because I thought it best to explain  via screenshots of what i had done before.. what’s the problem.. the code is wrong??

Comment: i havent checked the code but it's better to copypaste the code and apply code format. This helps with SEO and its also easy to copy paste something to your own code to try it out.